# Google sign-in fails

Tags: android, google-signin

I try to use Google sign-in. I wrote this code two months ago and it worked fine and when I came back to the code this week it just won't connect. I checked in Google's tutorial but nothing has changed.

The only thing I changed were the versions in the gradle files, but I tried to change them again and it didn't help.

I read that "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" occurs when there's a big image, but I have no image here.

Can someone tell me what am I missing? This is the code:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.d("Login", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        assert signInButton != null;
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                }
                }
        });

}


    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("Login Google", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(this, "User name: " + acct.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

private void signIn() {
        Log.v("Login", "SignIn");
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
}
```

Project grade:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' 
    }
```

App gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2' // Google Sign-in
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Sign-in
}
```

This is what I get in the logcat:

```
07-26 10:41:53.275 V/Login: SignIn
07-26 10:41:53.433 E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1442828)
07-26 10:41:53.764 D/Login Google: handleSignInResult:false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed another thing... the computer I work on.
I updated the SHA1 fingerprint and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

try move

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` outside from the dependencies.

Like this

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2' // Google Sign-in
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Sign-in
```